# nav menu won't line up horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-lists

i'm trying to get a horizontal navigation bar, but I can't get it to work right.

http://jsfiddle.net/2fkxx/

```
nav {
    text-align: center;
}
    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
        nav ul li {
            display: inline;
        }
            nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                width: 80px;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `li` to `inline-block` rather than `inline`.

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fkxx/2/)

Answer (score 2):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2fkxx/1/)

```
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

Set 'float:left' for the list element and also do 'display:inline-block'

```
nav ul li{
   float:left;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Let me know if it worked. I have had the same problem recently. I can help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try using inline-block instead of block

```
nav ul{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `float:right` on `nav ul li` visit [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/fYLTY/1/)

```
nav ul li {
     float:left;
     display: inline;
        }
```